# Is it possible to easily migrate data from light SQL Server Express to Azure with a dacpac file?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm currently trying to deploy a website with Azure which I did following these steps 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-aspnet-core-ef-step-05?view=vs-2019#publish-to-azure-app-service
however the data from the database didn't get saved, like it did in the video. I think this may be because I have 2 data contexts; one for users and one for general app models.

I believe I have to figure out how to migrate my data from SQL Server Express provided by Entity Framework to Azure.

[image: Visual Studio image from database]

It seems like it should be doable from this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/targets/azure-sqldb?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

but then this [one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-export) makes it sound like you need a .bak file.

Just want to know if my Visual Studio data can easily transferred to Azure this way. would it be easier to publish my "data tier application" or extract and copy what I need to azure. Kind of overwhelmed at all the documentation trying to find the easiest way the small amount of data for my test website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to migrate my data from SQL Server Express provided by Entity Framework to Azure?

No you can not do that, import and export feature is not available with SQL Server Express. You can reference this link: [Limitations of SQL Server Express](https://www.dotnetspider.com/tutorials/SqlServer-Tutorial-158.aspx).

As you posted the screen shoot, no function can help you migrate the database to Azure.
[image]

So if you really want migrate the database from local SQL Server to Azure, you'd better using the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio(SSMS). There are so many ways, such as:

1. [Migrate on-premises SQL Server or SQL Server on Azure VMs to Azure SQL Database using the Data Migration Assistant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/dma/dma-migrateonpremsqltosqldb?view=sql-server-2017)
2. [Tutorial: Migrate SQL Server to a single database or pooled database in Azure SQL Database offline using DMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dms/tutorial-sql-server-to-azure-sql)
3. [Copy data to and from SQL Server by using Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sql-server)
4. [Migrating SQL Database to Azure SQL Database using SSMS Export/Import](http://www.techmixing.com/2018/11/how-to-migrate-sql-database-to-azure-sql-database-using-ssms-export-import.html)

If you are first time to migrate, we suggest to you use the A[zure Data Migration Assistant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/dma/dma-overview?view=sql-server-2017) as Alberto Morillo said.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Before trying to migrate the database to Azure you need to first verify the database and its objects are compatible to Azure SQL Database. If you don't do that the migration may fail.

My suggestion is to use [Azure Data Migration Assistant](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53595) (DMA) to perform an assessment of your database and make sure there are no blocking points that can make the migration not possible. Make adjustments based on the report generated by the DMA tool and then use any migration method (including extracting\importing a Data-tier Application) to migrate your database to Azure SQL Database. DMA can also migrate your database to Azure SQL Database and for me is the easiest way to do it.

About restoring a native backup to Azure SQL Database, that is not possible. You can export your database as bacpac and then import it to Azure SQL Database, or you can use DMA or Data Migration Service to migrate your databases to Azure SQL Database.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what is already said . You can dump all the data in txt or csv file and put that in the local drive . In Azure we have the Azure data factory (ADF)  , which has a copy activity , this is very powerful and looks like will be good for your scenario . As mentioned before the data types are the key . You will have to install something called integrated Runtime ( IR ) and it should work .